# Add a MongoDB non-primary member to an existing replica set from the member itself

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

We are trying to setup a MongoDB replica set combined with AWS EC2 Autoscaling group so the replica set can heal itself without human interference when one server is down.

Everything is to be done by bootstrap script on each instance.

Here's how we plan to do it:
1 The first instance start the replica set and set itself as primary
2 Each time a new instance is added to the autoscaling group, the new instance connects to one member of the existing replica set, ask who is the primary
3 The new instance makes a connection to primary, add itself to the replica set through primary

My question is, is adding new member to the replica set through a connection to primary doable?

In current mongodb javascript scripting, I can make a connection to the primary by:
conn = new Mongo();

Then there is rs.add() to add member.

How can you call rs.add() through a Mongo() connection to add new member on the new member itself? I read through the documents and couldn't find a way to retrieve rs object from a Mongo() connection.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of mongodb are you using?  Which javascript driver/version?

Comment: mongo version 3.2, doc didn't really say which version is the javascript

Comment: Isn't additoin script has to be executed from primary only ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below.

### Determine which is the primary.

PRIMARY=`/usr/bin/mongo ${IP}:27017 --eval "printjson(rs.isMaster())" | grep "primary" | cut -d"\"" -f4`

### Connecting to the primary to add the new node.

R=`/usr/bin/mongo ${PRIMARY}/admin --eval "printjson(rs.add('${NEW_NODE_IP}:27017'))"`

Note: NEW_NODE_IP is the IP of newly added EC2.

Comment: Is there a way to add all new nodes in one shot.